# New GIT branch become new base or am I missing something?

Tags: git, visual-studio, branch

I am net to GIT so I might have misunderstod some of the things I've learned.

I use GIT in Visual Studio 2017 and sync it to my account in VSTS.
I've checked out a branch before - made some changed that was committed, merged and synced with master.

Now - when I try to check out a new local branch from master - the new branch get's displayed BELOW the master branch. Then other branch I checked out, committed, merged and synced was displayed ABOVE the master branch.

Maybe it doesn't matter? But I can't find any place where this behaviour is described. I looks as if the new branc become the new base?

My quesion is: Why does the new branch show BELOW the master when it previously was shown ABOVE the master?
[Visual studio branch view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFYRJ.png)

Comment: I assume the list is sorted alphabetically and doesn’t show anything about how the branches relate to each other

Comment: OMG !! It was as simple as that :-D Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in [Sami Kuhmonen's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51057235/new-git-branch-become-new-base-or-am-i-missing-something#comment89104971_51057235):

> I assume the list is sorted alphabetically and doesn’t show anything about how the branches relate to each other.

It's worth adding, however, that there's something else important to know here: **Git branches do not have any inherent relationships.**  There is no such thing as the parent branch of some other branch.

What makes this confusing is that *commits* **do** have parent/child relationships, and in one sense, branches are made up of commits.  So it seems like branches should also have them.  The problem is that when we say *branches* right here, we mean the *branch names*, like `master` and `develop`.  These names are merely user-changeable names that Git provides for us to keep track of *one single commit*.  That one single commit that each branch name remembers is called the *tip* of the branch:

```
A  <-B  <-C   <--master
```

Each actual commit has some big ugly hash ID as its real name, and those are impossible for humans to work with, so we have the name `master` to remember the hash ID of commit `C`.  Commit `C` remembers the hash ID of its parent `B`, and `B` remembers the hash ID of its parent `A`.  (`A` is the first commit ever made in this tiny three-commit repository, so it has no parent and the action stops here: since it's first, that's the end of history, in Git's backwards-looking fashion.)

To make a new commit, Git writes out the new commit with its new unique hash ID—let's just call it `D`—and then updates the *name* `master` to store `D`'s hash ID.  `D` itself contains `C`'s hash ID, so that Git can find `C` from `D`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

Once a commit is made, it can *never* be changed (at all—changing anything gives you a *new* commit, with a new unique hash ID, so the old commit has not changed!).  We know the internal arrows always point backwards, so there's no need to draw those.  When we make a new branch *name*, however, we end up with two names pointing to the same commit:

```
A--B--C   <-- master, develop (HEAD)
```

Now we need to attach `HEAD` to a branch name, so that we know which one we're on!  If we make commit `D` now, the branch name that moves is `develop`:

```
A--B--C   <-- master
       \
        D   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

But we can use `git reset` to *move* branch names around at any time.  For instance, if we don't like `D` after all, and want to have `develop` start from `B`, we can `git reset` it and make things look like this:

```
A--B   <-- develop (HEAD)
    \
     C   <-- master
      \
       D  [abandoned, will go away in about a month]
```

If we now make a new commit `E`, the parent of `E` will be `B`, and the visible part will look like this:

```
A--B--E   <-- develop (HEAD)
    \
     C   <-- master
```

(Commit `D` has no way to find it—it is *unreachable* in Git terms—so we can't see it by normal means.)

#### Conclusion

Keep in mind that each branch *name* is just a pointer, pointing to one (1) commit, as in the drawings above.  Git uses the *commits* to find their parents, following the chain from "where the name points" backwards through history.  But you will find that when people talk about "a branch" in Git, they often don't mean the *name*, but rather *the commits reached by starting at the name and moving backwards*.  You have to figure out from context whether someone means "the name"" or "the set of commits".  For more about this, see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)